# returning null with PLINQ

Tags: c#, plinq

i have an extension method for IEnumerable which then iterates through the collection, doing its business, and then returns an new IEnumerable.

I have tried to use PLINQ using .AsParallel().ForAll() which speeds up the iterations significantly (which of course it should do) however when the collection is returned, there are often a few objects in that collection that are null.

I'm assuming this may be because it is returning the collection before all the 'business' has a chance to complete? if i debug and put in a breakpoint, there are no nulls.

is there some sort of 'wait for this operation to be completed' method that i should be using?

**EDIT:** to be a bit clearer, there is business logic in the forall, modifying properties etc. it's necessary to have an action looped, rather than simply selecting something.

Comment: Can you show us a code sample?

Comment: ParallelEnumerable<T>.ForAll() doesn't return anything (void ForAll(...)), not an IEnumerable<T> - if you're using ForAll, you're not returning an enumerable... You'll need to show code.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. the method returns the collection, not the forall.

Comment: upon further investigation, this may because a List<T> is not thread safe (i read this on a blog). The data i am iterating over is of List<T>, which may well be the issue. as it turns out the performance I gain from doing what I need to do in parallel is so small I'm not going to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by *returning*, because the `ForAll` method doesn't return anything. It invokes the delegate you specify in parallel for all elements of the collection. I would suppose that your code looks like this:

```
data.AsParallel().ForAll(() => /* calculate and store result somewhere */);
// more code
```

The `ForAll` method doesn't wait for all delegates to complete, so `more code` can execute before all the delegates complete (and you also need to be careful in the `store result somewhere` bit, because it may run concurrently for multiple delegates!)

I think the code could be rewritten more elegantly using the `Select` method:

```
var res = data.AsParallel().Select(() => /* calculate the result */);
```

In this case, the delegate simply returns the result. The `Where` method collects all the results and when you iterate over the returned `IEnumerable`, it guarantees that all delegates finished calculating.

Comment: thanks tom - sorry for the ambiguity, the method returns the collection, it can't be returned from the forall - there's too much business logic in there.

Comment: In that case, you need to be really careful, because actions are executing concurrently - you almost certainly need some locks. PLINQ is best used when you have code that "returns a result" (aka is functional) rather than "modifies a state" (aka is imperative).

Answer (score 0):

`ForAll()` doesn't perform a merge, and returns immediately.  `Parallel.ForEach()` is probably the functionality you're looking for.

ie instead of:

`collection.AsParallel().ForAll( t=>t.doWork() );`

something like

`Parallel.ForEach(collection.AsParallel(), t=>t.doWork());`

Comment: hmmm.. no good - Parallel.ForEach(collection, t=>t.doWOrk()); causes same problem, and Parallel.ForEach(collection.AsParallel(), t=>t.doWork()); throws an aggregate exception

Comment: Odd... `Parallel.ForEach()` returns a `ParallelLoopResult` which has an `IsCompleted` property that you could check.  I'd look into the contents of the `AggregateException` though, maybe something isn't happening correctly in your `doWork()` function.